# PHP MYSQL Batch update

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone tell me why I cannot perform this simple script.  The error I get is `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1update page SET RegionId = 1  WHERE (RegionId = -1 or RegionId = -3) and Descri' at line 1`  If I copy this statement in to MySQLPHPAdmin it runs fine.  Please help?  Thanks in advance.

```
$sql = "update page SET RegionId = 2  WHERE (RegionId = -1 or RegionId = -3) and Description like '%Saskatoon%' LIMIT 1";
$sql = $sql . "update page SET RegionId = 1  WHERE (RegionId = -1 or RegionId = -3) and Description like '%Regina%' LIMIT 1";

echo $sql;

mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error());
```

Comment: This exact code **cannot** throw such error

Answer (score 6):

The semicolon in your query is being removed and the LIMIT 1 is clashing with the beginning of the second update query.

From the PHP.net mysql_query manual page: mysql_query() sends a unique query **(multiple queries are not supported)** to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.

You will need to use 2 calls to mysql_query to get the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

You're concatenating those two `$sql` strings, so the final `$sql` string will have a part that looks like:

```
LIMIT 1update page SET
```

which is invalid SQL. In addition, `mysql_query` doesn't support multiple queries (thanks zerkms), so you'll have to execute each one separately.

```
$sql = "UPDATE page SET RegionId = 2 WHERE (RegionId = -1 OR RegionId = -3) AND Description LIKE '%Saskatoon%' LIMIT 1"
mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error());
$sql = "UPDATE page SET RegionId = 1 WHERE (RegionId = -1 OR RegionId = -3) AND Description LIKE '%Regina%' LIMIT 1";
mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error());
```

Comment: `mysql_query()` doesn't support several queries in a string

Comment: OK, you've found, where that one comes from, but: "mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported)" http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php So he needs to send both queries one after another…

Answer (score 0):

If `1update page set …` isn't a typo, then this is the cause of the error. Try to find out where those one is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

As said in other answers, mysql_query() does not support multiple queries, if you want to optimize this into one query you may have to re-think the way the query works.

if you are willing to give up the Limit 1 restriction you could do it this way:

```
$sql = "update page 
    SET RegionId = 2  WHERE (RegionId = -1 or RegionId = -3) and Description like '%Saskatoon%',
    SET RegionId = 1  WHERE (RegionId = -1 or RegionId = -3) and Description like '%Regina%'";
```

Because you are using like's on strings as your final conditional this could update many records, i would suggest re-designing to use ID's so you could engineer your query with better restrictions, for example:

```
$sql = "update page 
    SET RegionId = 2  WHERE (`RegionId` = -1 or `RegionId` = -3) and `user` = '1',
    SET RegionId = 1  WHERE (`RegionId` = -1 or `RegionId` = -3) and `user` = '2'";
```